# Синтаксическая ошибка при выборке категории с максимальной суммой цен

Tags: sql, select, aggregate

Таблица `Products` выглядит следующим образом:

[image: База данных]

Я хочу из нее выбрать категории с максимальной суммой цен.
Для этого у меня есть такой вариант запроса:

```
select categoryID, sum(Price)
from Products
group by categoryID
having sum(Price) >= all (
select sum(Price)
from Products
group by categoryID
)
```

Но на него выходит такая синтаксическая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если заменить `all` на `max`:

```
select categoryID, sum(Price)
from Products
group by categoryID
having sum(Price) = max (
select sum(Price)
from Products
group by categoryID
)
```

То тоже синтаксическая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю, и как это исправить. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Не знаю ругается ли на заглавные буквы. На картинке у вас categoryID с большой, а в коде с маленькой.

Comment: Таки нет, заменила categoryID на CategoryID, но ошибка та же самая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Максимальную сумму можно искать подзапросом.

```
select categoryID, sum(Price)
from Products
group by categoryID
having sum(Price) >= (
  select max(sm) from (
    select sum(Price) as sm
    from Products
    group by categoryID
  )
)
```

Comment: Таки непонятно почему >= all не работает. Вроде он для таких моментов и нужен.

Comment: Потому что у вас условие стоит не в том месте.

Comment: Что значит "не в том месте"?